# Series proof $\sum_1^\infty|a_n|<\infty$ then show that $\sum_1^\infty{a_n^2}<\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Iam stuck with this proof. There seems to be no property to help.
If $\sum_1^\infty|a_n|<\infty$ then show that $\sum_1^\infty{a_n^2}<\infty$ and that the reverse isnt true.

Comment: Well a well known example that the converse is not true is the sum of inverse of squares and the harmonic sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first series converges, so $|a_n|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Because of this, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|a_n|<1$. If $|a_n|<1$, then $a_n^2<|a_n|$. Eventually the terms of the new series are less than the terms of the old series. Then by direct comparison, the new series converges.

As for a counterexample to the reverse statement, other answers have already brought up the [harmonic and over-harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: great explanation. however it seems that there should be a $n>N$

Comment: @Parhs, I have added it.

Comment: My problem is that in case $a_n$ in the beginning before $a_n$<1 ,$a_n^2$ is way larger and produce a bigger sum

Comment: @Parhs: But you see, before $a_n<1$ there exists only a finite number of terms. It does not matter how much larger $a_n^2$ is, as the finite sum of finite terms is finite.

Comment: So direct comparison doesnt necesarily mean something for their sums (comparison) ,interesting .eg $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{100}{n^2}\right)^2 $ > $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ . thanks

Comment: @Parhs: It is true that the series with $a_n^2$ can be much larger than the series with $|a_n|$, but both will converge. By "direct comparison" I meant this convergence test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test

Comment: teacher told me that this is poor proof and not valid and that there is simpler one.

Comment: @Parhs: Why is it a poor proof? Of course, it is not a fully rigorous representation, but it should not be difficult at all to generate one from this.

Comment: I dont know he didnt tell me.Maybe he is going to tell me but I am not sure if he will. In case I'll post it. I'll show him this again...

Comment: @Parhs: If you find out what the simpler proof is, or why this one is poor, please let me know in the comments here.

Comment: I am going to ask why it is poor but probably he isnt going to tell me(cant insist he'll get annoyed).However after asking lots of other classmates someone showed me the solution . It is like this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/493782/17446 .

Answer (score 3):

$\sum_1^\infty{a_n^2} \leq (\sum_1^\infty|a_n|)(\sum_1^\infty|a_n|) < \infty$

A example to show reverse untrue.

See $a_n = \frac {1}{n} $

Comment: Ok but why this inequality is true ?

Comment: @Syuizen how did you come up with the inequality ?

Comment: @Parhs $\forall n , a_n^2 \leq |a_n|(\sum_1^\infty|a_n|) \Rightarrow  \sum_1^\infty{a_m^2} \leq (\sum_1^\infty|a_m|)(\sum_1^\infty|a_n|)$

Comment: did you figured out randomly the $ a_n^2 \leq |a_n|(\sum_1^\infty|a_n|)$?

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Does $a_n^2\le |a_n|$ eventually hold? What do you know about the harmonic series?

Comment: it doesnt hold .But how do harmonic series relate? they are $1/n^r$ not $1/a_n^r$

Comment: think again....

Comment: phd professor told me that this is really poor and unacceptable ...

Comment: @Parhs it was only a hint. The work of turning this into a solution to the problem was left for you. Besides, please avoid leaving meaningless remarks such as "Mr. so and so, who happens to hold a PhD, told me this is really poor, but either did not supply any more criticism, or if any such criticism was supplied I'll just keep it to myself so that I leave a cryptic remark".

Comment: Yes it is pointless. However in case I get a solution I'll share it.

Comment: You already have more than one solution.

Comment: I have solutions which are fine but are not acceptable from professor. (I study computer science)