# If squared series is convergent then series is convergent absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

If $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n^2$ is convergent, does that imply $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n$ is convergent?

How can I prove that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No.  $a_n=1/n$...

Comment: $1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6+17+1/8+...... \ge 1+1/2+(1/4+1/4)+(1/8+1/8+1/8+1/8)+... =1+1/2+1/2+1/2+...=\infty$, while for$ n \ge 2$, we have $\sum_{j=2}^{j=n}< \sum_{j=2}^{j=n} (j(j-1))^{-1}=\sum_{j=1}^{j=n} (1/(j-1)-1/j=1-1/n$

Comment: |Are you familiar with the Cauchy condensation test?  If  $A(n) /ge A(n+1) \ge 0$  then  $\sum_n A(n)$ converges iff  $\sum_n 2^n A(2^n)$  converges

Comment: The converse would be a slightly more interesting question.

Answer (score 6):

We have the counterexample $a_n=\frac1n$.  The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ converges.  But the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n}$ is divergent.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answers, $a_k=\frac1n$ is a counterexample, since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{n}$ diverges and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ converges. If you want to see proofs of these facts, you can look here:

- [Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ not converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/255)
- [Need to prove the sequence $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333417/need-to-prove-the-sequence-a-n-1-frac122-frac132-cdots-frac1n) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/333417)
- If you are also interested in the value of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$: [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/8337)

The implication in the opposite direction is true for $a_k>0$, i.e., for series with positive terms. See [Prove that if $\sum{a_n}$ converges absolutely, then $\sum{a_n^2}$ converges absolutely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493756/prove-that-if-suma-n-converges-absolutely-then-suma-n2-converges-abs) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/493756).

Answer (score 2):

Not true. Take $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

take $a_n=1/n$

then $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent while $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent