# if $(a_{n})$ is bounded and $\sum(b_{n})$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum(a_{n}b_{n})$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I prove that if $(a_{n})$ is bounded and $\sum(b_{n})$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum(a_{n}b_{n})$ is absolutely convergent?

I tried to consider the sequence of partial sums of $\sum |a_nb_n|$

$S_n=|a_1b_1|+|a_2b_2|+......+|a_nb_n|$

Comment: And so $S_n \le M (|b_1| + ... + |b_n|)$ for a fixed $M$, so....

Comment: Hint: What does it mean for $(a_n)$ to be bounded?

Comment: If you understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493756/prove-that-if-suma-n-converges-absolutely-then-suma-n2-converges-abs/493782#493782) answer, you should be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$(a_n) $ bounded
$$\implies (\exists M\ge 0)\;\;(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\;\; |a_n|\le M $$

$$\implies |a_nb_n|\le M|b_n|$$

and
$\sum |b_n|$ convergent
$\implies \sum M|b_n|$ convergent.

You conclude by comparison test.