# $\sum a_n\text{ converges}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_0 a_n+a_1 a_{n-1}+a_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}a_{\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil}\right)=\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Does $\ \displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n\ \text{ converges}\ \implies\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( a_0 a_n + a_1 a_{n-1} + a_2 a_{n-2} + a_{ \big\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \big\rfloor  } a_{ \big\lceil \frac{n}{2} \big\rceil } \right)\ $ converges?

And if it doesn't converge for conditionally convergent series $\ \displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n\ $, then does it converge for absolutely convergent series $\ \displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n\ $?

If we try to use Cauchy-Schwarz, we get:

$$ \left( a_0 a_n + \ldots +  a_{ \big\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \big\rfloor  } a_{ \big\lceil \frac{n}{2} \big\rceil } \right)^2$$

$$ \leq \left( {a_0}^2 + {a_1}^2 + \ldots + {\left( a_{ \big\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \big\rfloor  }\right)}^2 \right) \left( {a_n}^2 + {a_{n-1}}^2 + \ldots + {\left( a_{ \big\lceil \frac{n}{2} \big\rceil  }\right)}^2 \right).$$

On the right-hand side, the first bracket could $\ \to \infty,\ $ and I'm not sure what you can say about the second bracket, but even if you could show that the second bracket $\ \to 0\ $ as $\ n\to\infty\ $ (which I am not sure of), the right hand side is still indeterminate, so C-S doesn't seem to help.

Also for example if $\ a_n = \frac{1}{n^2},\ $ then I'm not sure what $\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( a_0 a_n + a_1 a_{n-1} + a_2 a_{n-2} + a_{ \big\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \big\rfloor  } a_{ \big\lceil \frac{n}{2} \big\rceil } \right)\ $ is. Perhaps this can be made into an integral? Although I'm not sure how to do this either.

Comment: If the series is absolutely convergent, then I think your CS argument shows the expression in question does converge. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493756/prove-that-if-suma-n-converges-absolutely-then-suma-n2-converges-abs). If the sequence is not absolutely convergent, say a sequence with oscillating positive/negative terms, then maybe you can show the expression in question oscillates between something with positive lower bound and something with negative upper bound.

Comment: @RodLaver Yes and the limit will be zero, because
$$\left\lvert\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}a_k\,a_{n-k}\right\rvert\le\left(\sup_{\lceil\frac n2\rceil\le k\le n}|a_k|\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}|a_k|,$$
where the $\sup$ tends to $0$ and the $\sum$ is bounded. I suspect one can build a counterexample when the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: This is strongly related to the Cauchy product of series and Merten's theorem. If $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely then the Cauchy product $\sum c_n$ of $\sum a_n$ with itself is convergent, which implies that $c_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it does converge for absolutely convergent series, but not necessarily for
simply convergent ones.

For non-absolute convergent series a counterexample is:

$$
a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

For absolutely convergent $a_n$ introduce $b_n$:

$$
b_n = \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} a_j a_{n-j}
$$

$$
b_{2m} = \sum_{j=0}^m  a_j a_{m-j} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{2m} a_j a_{m-j} + \frac{1}{2} a_m^2
$$
$$
b_{2m+1} = \sum_{j=0}^m  a_j a_{m-j} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{2m+1} a_j a_{m-j} 
$$

Using $f_n = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j a_{n-j}$ we get:
$$
  \left|b_n - f_n\right| \leq
  \left|a^2_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\right|
$$
which means that $b_n$ converges if and only if $f_n$ converges. But $f_n$ converges because
$$
  2f_n = \left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j \right)^2  -
  \sum_{j=0}^n a_j^2
$$
which proves the convergence of $b_n$ as well.

Comment: +1. The comment to the Q by @nejimban also shows that we do have convergence to $0$ if $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.  Also I think we may have convergence to $0$ for some conditionally convergent  $\sum a_n$ . Perhaps if $a_n=(-1)^n/(n+1)?$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Indeed, in this case
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}a_k\,a_{n-k}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{n-k+1}\right)\sim\frac{(-1)^n}n\log n.$$

Comment: (In the $a_n:=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ case we can show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}a_k\,a_{n-k}\sim\frac{(-1)^n\pi}2$ using a Riemann sum argument.)

Comment: I think there is a mistake/typo in the answer.  If $$
b_n = \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} a_j a_{n-j}
$$
then
$$
b_{2m} \neq \sum_{j=0}^m  a_j a_{m-j}.$$

In the first sum, $b_6 = a_0 a_6 + a_1 a_5 + a_2 a_4 + a_3^2,\ $ whereas in the second sum, $b_6 = a_0 a_3 + a_1 a_2 + a_2 a_1 + a_3 a_0.$

Comment: Thahk you @AdamRubinson. You are right, there  was a typo there, which I've just fixed.